# Hive - How to store a query result in a variable in a Bash script

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

I need to store the result of a Hive query in a variable whose value will be used later. So, something like:

```
$var = select col1 from table;

$var_to_used_later = $var;
```

All this is part of a bash shell script. How to form the query so as to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Hive should provide command line support for you. I am not familiar with hive but I found this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli, you can check whether that works.

Personally, I used mysql to achieve similar goal before. The command is:

`` mysql -u root -p`[script to generate the key]` -N -B -e "use XXXDB; select aaa, bbb, COUNT(*) from xxxtable where some_attribute='$CertainValue';" ``

Comment: I should have been clearer. I am running a bash script, of which what I am trying to achieve is merely a part. I am not using the Hive CLI directly, but rather trying to get a query to run from within a Bash script.

Comment: you make me more confused. Is your question how to use the bash variable from your query?

Answer (score 0):

I used the method shown [here](https://linuxandryan.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/run-hive-from-bash-script-loop-through-file/) and got it! Instead of calling a file as shown, I run the query directly and use the value stored in the variable.

Comment: This is exactly what I was suggesting, except I didn't provide the code.